# Connect database in Testcontainer during debugging?

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker, testing, integration-testing

I am using test container for my Integration Test in a Spring Boot app and trying to connect database in the composed Docker container.

However, I cannot connect even using the given url and credentials in my properties file:

```
spring:
  datasource:
    driver-class-name: org.testcontainers.jdbc.ContainerDatabaseDriver
    url: jdbc:tc:postgresql:14.6-alpine:///employees_db
    username: sa
    password: 123456
```

On the other hand, when I debug the test, there is completely a different url on the console with a different database name.

```
Database: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:64880/test (PostgreSQL 14.6)
```

I tried to connect using both of them via Host and Url connection of DBeaver, but get error ("authentication failed or connection refused errors).

So, how can I connect this database during debugging a test method (pausing with breakpoint).

Answer (score 1):

If it is still relevant for you, I faced the same issue.
My `application-test.yml`:

```
spring:
  jpa:
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: validate
  datasource:
    driver-class-name: org.testcontainers.jdbc.ContainerDatabaseDriver
    url: jdbc:tc:postgresql:9.6.8://hostname/pc_db?TC_DAEMON=true
```

and my console output during the test run:

> Database: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:52957/pc_db (PostgreSQL 9.6)

finally I was able to connect the test DB with these properties:

- URL: `jdbc:postgresql://localhost:52957/pc_db`
- User: `test`
- Password: `test`

**Note** that the DB port is generated randomly on each test run!
And each time you should take it from the test logs!

Comment: Creds test:test worked, thanks!